# Strapi v4 Azure Storage Provider Still Save Files To Local Server

Tags: strapi

I am using strapi v4. Although I use [Strapi azure storage provider](https://github.com/jakeFeldman/strapi-provider-upload-azure-storage), it still saves files to local server.

I did all the implementation as it was said.I tried everything but it didn't work.Can you help with this?

I also followed the instructions below

https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/deployment/azure

Comment: We are facing this issue. Did you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

We had faced the same issue and the issue was due to a minor step missed in the setup. As per the documentation, the plugin should be under "./config/env/production/" folder in order to get picked in the production mode.

https://docs.strapi.io/cloud/advanced/upload#configure-the-provider

> To configure a 3rd-party upload provider in your Strapi project,
> create or edit the plugins configuration file for your production
> environment ./config/env/production/plugins.js|ts by adding upload
> configuration options as follows: